# jq: 1 compile error jq: error: schedule/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1: .Christchurch.bus-schedule.from["Weekday"] |= . + ["1646"]

Tags: reactjs, compilation, jq, yarnpkg, toplevel

I have a react application which uses a .sh file to generate a part of the application. But I have come across an error which prevents the application from reading the data files.

I've looked at versioning, possible syntax changes in the .sh file which is `emap.sh`

This is the `.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
object='{}'

find 'public/data' -type f -name '*.csv' | while read -r filename;
do
    filename=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/public\/data\///' | sed 's/ /\//')
    city=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'/' -f1)
    medium=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'/' -f2)
    direction=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'/' -f3)
    date=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'/' -f4)
    time=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'/' -f5| head -c-5)
    object=$(echo $object | jq -c ".$city.$medium.$direction[\"$date\"] |= . + [\"$time\"]")
    echo $object > public/available.json
done
```

It should be successful so that when we yarn the application, it shows up having read the data, but we get a page without data in the area using the information that needs to be processed.

Comment: Passing bash variables such as $city to jq in the way it is done in the script is asking for trouble.  Consider using jq's `--arg` command-line option instead. Note that this will entail small changes in the jq script as well.

Comment: @peak this whole task can be accomplished using only `find` and `jq` right? what OP does with `object` in while loop is exactly what `reduce`/`foreach` does

Comment: @oguzismail - Looking at the script makes my head spin, so I just focused on the invocation of jq ...

Answer (score 1):

The shell variables should be passed to jq in a more robust manner, e.g. along these lines:

```
jq -c --arg city "$city" \
      --arg medium "$medium" \
      --arg direction "$direction" \
      --arg date "$date" \
      --arg time "$time" \
   '.[$city][$medium][$direction][$date] += [$time]'
```

As @OguzIsmail points out, though, you would probably be better off avoiding all the messiness by doing everything with just `find` and `jq`.